# Full Calendar Style Reset

Tags: css, wordpress, fullcalendar

We're trying to integrate Full Calendar on the front-end of a WordPress site. The problem we are facing is that most WordPress themes have custom styles that alter the appearance of tables, making Full Calendar look broken.

I'm no CSS expert, so any help is greatly appreciated. Is there any way to reset the styles so that Full Calendar's own styles are always applied to the same style set, regardless of any other styles that may be loaded on the page?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to remove their css, and add your css class there.

this works for me (version v1.5.4),

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({

  ...

  ,eventRender: function(event, element) {   //render how event look like
    // example add element
    element.attr("category",event.title);

    //example to remove the original color
    //element.find("div").removeClass("fc-event-skin fc-event-inner");
    //OR
    //element.find("div").css({"background-color":"transparent","border-color":"transparent"});
    //element.css({"background-color":event.colors,"border-color":"transparent"});

    //example to add class
    if(event.title === "big_event"){
       element.addClass("calred");
    }
  },
  viewDisplay   : function(view) {   //render how calendar look like
    //example coloring on sat,sun
    $(".fc-sat, .fc-sun").addClass("ss-holiday");
    $("th.fc-sat, th.fc-sun").removeClass("ss-holiday");
  }

  ...

});
```